# How to get JSON data from the URL (REST API) to UI using jQuery or plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rest, jquery

I have a URL "`http://localhost:8888/api/rest/abc`" which will give following json data. I wants to get this data in my UI using Jquery or java script. I'm trying this from couple of hours but I'm unable to resolve it. Please Suggest me few solutions which will help me to resolve this problem.

```
{
  "My-user": [
    {
      "link": [
        {
          "href": "http://localhost:8888/api/rest/abc/MI/CH",
          "rel": "self",
          "type": "application/my.My.My-user+xml",
          "title": "rln"
        },
        {
          "href": "http://localhost:8888/api/rest/cabin?MI=mi&CH=ch",
          "rel": "some relation",
          "type": "application/my.My.My-cabin+xml",
          "title": "rln1"
        }
      ],
      "My-user-list": [
        {
          "name": "cuba",
          "Explanation": "bark"
        }
      ],
      "CH": "ch",
      "MI": "mi",
      "password": "xyz",
    },
    {
      "link": [
        {
          "href": "http://localhost:8888/api/rest/abc/DD/KN",
          "rel": "self",
          "type": "application/my.My.My-user+xml",
          "title": "rln"
        },
        {
          "href": "http://localhost:8888/api/rest/cabin?DD=dd&KN=kn",
          "rel": "some relation",
          "type": "application/my.My.My-cabin+xml",
          "title": "rln1"
        }
      ],
      "My-user-list": [
        {
          "name": "Cuba1",
          "Explanation": "bark1"
        }
      ],
      "KN": "kn",
      "DD": "dd",
      "password": "xyz1",
    }
  ]
}
```

---

I have tried Getjson which is not working out for me this is my code below Please correct me if the code is wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.getJSON('/api/rest/abc', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is expected output, show us the code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Nil this Url is generated through Node.js and after starting the server If i open the URL after running the server localhost:8888/api/rest/abc then it wil give following json but i want that json to be in the UI

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Send a ajax request to your server like this in your js and get your result in success function.

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/rest/abc",
            type: "GET",

            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(resultData) {
                //here is your json.
                  // process it

            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            },

            timeout: 120000,
        });
```

at server side send response as json type.

And you can use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for your application.

Comment: *async: false* why on the earth?

Comment: I'm Using GET Method Will you please guide me to use it for GET method

Comment: @Sau have edited my answer.and click on accept if u accept this answer

Answer (score 10):

You can use native JS so you don't have to rely on external libraries.

(I will use some ES2015 syntax, a.k.a ES6, modern javascript)
[What is ES2015?](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/)

```
fetch('/api/rest/abc')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Do what you want with your data
    });
```

You can also capture errors if any:

```
fetch('/api/rest/abc')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Do what you want with your data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('An error ocurred', err);
    });
```

By default it uses `GET` and you don't have to specify headers, but you can do all that if you want. For further reference: [Fetch API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Response_objects)

Comment: Please check Fetch's cross-browser compatibility before using this, not all browsers recognize it. There is a polyfill available on Github, but I for one couldn't make heads or tails of the usage instructions.

Comment: Good point @JohnSmith
https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

Answer (score 6):

You can use us jquery function [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) :

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('/api/rest/abc', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried getJson and updatedthe code in my Question above its not working out for me can you please check my code and tell me where I have done the mistake.

Comment: what is the method of your web service GET or POST?

Comment: check the return type of your rest webservice is it return JSON like that "@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)"

Comment: Hi This API is generated with node.js I hv tried using HTTP Client and checked with the return type APPlication/json through which it shows the same Json so I believe it should be Application/json.

Comment: Content-Type: application/json this is what i have used in http rest client (header) to check the output of the url localhost:8888/api/rest/abc

Answer (score 3):

```
 jquery.ajax({
            url: `//your api url`
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
                        console.log(data);
                        `All you API data is here`
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your answer will make more sense if it also explains the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the exact same thing. The issue I continued to have was that the REST API returned {count, next, prev, object}.

I used some of the answers here to come up with this:

```
$.getJSON( "http://192.168.122.233/SiteName", function( data ) {
    const items = data.results;
    $.each(items, function( key, value ) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(value);
        console.log(value.site);
    });
});
```

returns:

```
0
> Object { id: 0, site: "test" }
test
1
> Object { id: 1, site: "test2" }
test2
```

I hope this helps someone.