# Return ajax data

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an ajax call in a `function` and I did not find a solution how to `return` the data:

```
function get_blog_post(id){

    var info="id="+id;
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'get_blog_post.php',
            data: info,
            success: function(data){
                return data;
            }
    });

}
```

The code above doesn't works. The `data` contains the right answer but I can't use it if I callthe `get_blog_post()` `function`.

:\

Comment: Nope you can't, because the function that invokes the Ajax call completes before the Ajax call finishes.

Comment: In success function you send your response data to another js function to process it.
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945278/how-to-get-json-data-from-the-urlrest-api-to-ui-using-jquery-or-java-script/15945449#15945449) might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function get_blog_post(id, callback){

    var info="id="+id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get_blog_post.php',
        data: info,
        success: function(data){
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}

get_blog_post(5, function(data){
    // use data here
});
```

OR set async = false (not recommended):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get_blog_post.php',
        data: info,
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            return data;
        }
    });
```

Comment: It works but I get this :Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at callback

Comment: No, it does not work :\

Comment: You should take a look at the data actually being returned; with Chrome for example you can see this under "XHR" you can also view this information in Firefox.

Comment: i had an another call .. sry. it works now. thanks

Comment: OMG I always asked myself how they made a callback. Too lazy to find out but now I know.

Answer (score 1):

The `success` function runs some time after the ajax call completes. That's the nature of asynchronous calls--like ajax in javascript.

That means you cant return it and have to do something with the data in that function. Perhaps it is text and you put it into a text area like:

```
success: function(data){
             $('textarea').val(data);
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide a callback method and do what ever you want to do inside it

```
function get_blog_post(id, callback){

    var info="id="+id;
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'get_blog_post.php',
            data: info,
            success: callback
    });

}
```